# Wagtail and Elasticsearch , Lookup "icontains"" not recognised

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, wagtail

I'm trying to run a search with Wagtail (5.2) and Elastic (7)

When I make a search for Users `wagtail_admin/users/?q=ffff` I got such error

```
FilterFieldError
Cannot filter search results with field "email". Please add index.FilterField('email') to User.search_fields
```

Then I add extra field to search fields in the code

```
class User:

   search_fields = [
        index.SearchField("name", partial_match=True),
        index.FilterField("email", partial_match=True),
    ]
```

But just got another error

```
FilterError /wagtail_admin/users/
Could not apply filter on search results: "email__icontains = ffff". Lookup "icontains"" not recognised.
```

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation of wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#index-searchfield), you need to use `SearchField` for full-text search, try replacing the `index.FilterField` with `index.SearchField`:

```py
class User:

   search_fields = [
        index.SearchField("name", partial_match=True),
        index.SearchField("email", partial_match=True),
    ]
```

Comment: Tried, getting `wagtail.search.backends.base.FilterFieldError: Cannot filter search results with field "email". Please add index.FilterField('email') to User.search_fields.`